# Suggest some Android and iPhone mobile app automation tools

Tags: automated-testing, android, appium, iphone, mobile-automation

Please suggest me some tools for Android and iPhone app automation testing. I have searched some, like - Appium, Calabash, MonkeyTalk, Selendroid, Robotium, etc.

I am confused to choose any one from above. Please assist me in choosing best automation testing tool so that I can start with better tool which should have following features:

1. Support for Android and iPhone as well (Android is highly needed,
   iPhone is optional)
2. Support for Continuous Integration
3. Tool should be Open Source and Free
4. Supported scripting language should have Java
5. Community should be active

Suggest some Android and iPhone mobile app automation tools.

Comment: Should be moved to software recommendation exchange.

Comment: @Peter : How to move a question from one community to another, as per your suggestion. I have tried editing the question but, option to move category not shown to me. Help, plz.

Comment: I had no idea how to do it but 10 secs of googling told me to flag the question for moderator attention, with suggestion to move to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ - Remember Google is your best friend :-)

Comment: Question moved to : http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31704/best-android-and-iphone-app-automation-tools

Answer (score 9):

There are number of tools available in the market like:-

> a) Robotium
> b) Uiautomator
> c) Espresso
> d) Appium
> e) Calabash

But my experience -I can suggest you **Appium** is the best tool for both Android & iOS mobile testing.
I'm working on appium from last 6 months in my organization it is pretty good.

> The main **advantages of using Appium** is-

1. cross-platform
2. Backend is Selenium so you will get all selenium functionality
3. Able to test iOS and Android
4. Continuous integration support
5. Doesn't require access to your source code or library. You are
   testing which you will actually ship.
6. supports multiple frameworks.
7. Supports automation of hybris, native and webapps.
8. open source (free)
9. Can run app through appium server without manipulating the app.
10. No source code required(unlike robotium)
11. CI compatible with jenkins, saucelabs(so far from my experience)
12. Able to run on selenium grid.
13. Doesn't require an APK for use, although automating certain apps

> There is also few **Disadvantages of Appium**:
>
> For Android, No Support for Android **API level < 17**. It means you want to use Android v-4.2 or greater version.

[image]

Comment: Please suggest some references to setup appium on Windows7 and tutorials for basic start it.

Comment: this blog is most useful to Set up Appium on Win-7. I was tried using this & it was really helpful.-
http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2015/09/appium-tutorials.html

Comment: If you have again any doubt/problems in set up, 
Let me Know i'll help you.