# Mobile Testing Tools Suggestions

Tags: automated-testing, tools, mobile, mobile-automation

So I’m looking in to automated mobile testing solution and need some suggestions from experience folks who are currently using such tools. So far I’ve evaluated “Silk Mobile” and couple other tools but it seems they all needs to be physically connected to computer via USB. Is there any tool out there which doesn’t requires such USB connection all the times (of course when setting initially is acceptable).

Comment: This question is duplicate of http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18328/suggest-some-android-and-iphone-mobile-app-automation-tools

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use appium for testing mobile application. I have listed a Few Advantages of using appium for native and hybrid applications

- Appium can be used to test both Android and iOS applications
- It is easy to learn since the syntax is very similar to selenium syntax
- It is an open source tool and has user community to assist you with questions and concerns

And there are a lot of other advantages, I would recommend you refer more details on appium website http://appium.io/

You can run Appium tests on physical devices as well as emulators. You may also run tests on a wide range of devices with different configuration on Amazon device farm