# What is the single best open source mobile automation tool(for iOS and Android) for mobile application testing

Tags: mobile-automation

Here I am looking for testing tool for mobile, What is the single best open source mobile automation tool(for iOS and Android both) for mobile application testing ?

Comment: define what you mean by "best"

Comment: See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/18329/8992

Comment: What different question(s) do you have or does that answer your question ?

Comment: Single tool that can be use for all kind of mobile testing in mostly used in market.